# .exe with folder path as parameter

Tags: parameters, exe, args

I created a code that needs a path as an args parameter. I let Visual Studio build a .exe and now im trying to give the shortcut a Parameter like: ...\ReadPDF.exe "C:\Kunden"

[.exe shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJO4c.png)

And here the Main method of my code and in that args i want the path to get passed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE3ME.png)

Or maybe there is another way i didnt think of...
Thanks for every help i can get

Comment: Please can you post your code as text so we can copy/paste/reproduce your error? thank you!

Comment: Thanks for willing to help but i already got the solution i just forgot to rebuild the exe so that my changes apply. So its eorking now :)